# problems with scheduler and rights

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, at

I have WinXP installed in `C:\WINDOWS\` with 2 accounts: `Administrator` and `user`. The second one is limited and used for main work, but I also know a password for Administrator.
I want to make an *alarm clock* via task scheduling, but I can't!

`AT` doesn't work, saying access is denied under admin as well as under user.
Ok, I've found an article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259907/en-us, stating `LocalSystem` account should have full access to root directory. No problem...

```
C:\>cacls \ /G LocalSystem:F
No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.
```

WHAT? Current rights:

```
C:\>cacls \
C:\ BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F
    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F
    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)R
    BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(special access:)
                      FILE_APPEND_DATA

    BUILTIN\Users:(CI)(IO)(special access:)
                          FILE_WRITE_DATA

    Everyone:R
```

Ok, I googled it more and found, there's `schtasks` command (formatting)

```
C:\>schtasks /create
  /sc DAILY
  /tn alarmtest3
  /tr "wmplayer c:\music\catgroove.mp3"
  /st 01:50:00
```

It even creates task, but they just do not run.

```
C:\>schtasks

TaskName                             Next Run Time            Status
==================================== ======================== ===============
alarm                                11:00:00, 28.02.2011
alarmtest                            Never                    Could not start
alarmtest3                           01:50:00, 24.02.2011     Could not start
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore          At logon time
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore          16:14:00, 23.02.2011
GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA            02:14:00, 23.02.2011
```

`Scheduler` is running:

```
C:\>net start | findstr Sched
   Avira AntiVir Scheduler
   Task Scheduler
```

How could I schedule something?

Comment: Is there a message in the event log when the task should have started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the scheduler log at c:\WINDOWS\SchedLgU.Txt
You should find the entry after you job.
It will say something like this, but probably have a non zero exit code:

```
Result: The task completed with an exit code of (0).
```

Did you try invoking this command interactively before scheduling it?
I suspect your problem is that wmplayer is not in the system path. You will probably need to invoke it with the full path.

Tried this, got error:

```
C:\>wmplayer c:\windows\media\recycle.wav
'wmplayer' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Tried this, the sound was played:

```
C:\>"c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" c:\windows\media\recycle.wav
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. I still don't understand why `AT` doens't work, though.